# Java: make package level constructor in a class accessible for outer packages. Allow only certain classes inside project access to constructor

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm developing a library and trying to keep everything organized. Thus, I have nested package structure and a single class that is supposed to have access to constructors to all other classes:

***This is my project structure:***

```
src
   main
      java
         main
            Main.java
         zoo
            Zoo.java
            animals
               Animal.java
               mammals
                  Dog.java
               fish
                  Salmon.java
               birds
                  Falcon.java
```

***This is the code I have in a main method:***

**Main.java**:

```
Zoo zoo = new Zoo(password);
Animal dog = zoo.getDog(name);
Animal salmon = zoo.getSalmon(name);
Animal falcon = zoo.getFalcon(name);
```

***I want to prevent a user from being able to create an animal directly (from outside of the `zoo` package):***

```
Animal dog = new Dog("Charlie");  //error - constructor isn't public
```

However I'm not sure how to accomplish it. I could put all classes inside the `zoo` package and make animal constructors only package-level accessible. **However, I would have to sacrifice the package structur**e and I'd rather not do that.

**Zoo.java**:

```
public class Zoo {
    private String password;

    public Zoo(String password)  {this.password = password;}

    public Dog getDog(String name)  {return new Dog(name);}

    public Salmon getSalmon(String name)  {return new Salmon(name);}

    public Falcon getFalcon(String name)  {return new Falcon(name);}
}
```

**Animal.java**:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected String name;
    public Animal(String name)  {this.name = name;}
}
```

**animals**:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name) {super(name);}
}
public class Salmon extends Animal {
     public Salmon(String name) {super(name);}
}
public class Falcon extends Animal {
    public Falcon(String name)  {super(name);}
}
```

So what can be done to accomplish the above? Pehaps there exists some pattern for it?

Comment: What makes you want to prevent access to the animal constructors?

Comment: @jaco0646 only users who have permission (say, workers of the Zoo who have logged in into Zoo with password) can create animals.

Comment: When you say _users_, do you mean developers integrating this library into their own code?

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes, them. `Zoo` basically represents a site's API. To create a `Zoo` object one must pass correct credentials. Without being logged in (having a `Zoo` object), other objects just can't be created, because they require those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve package structure and make sure the user will instantiate animals using Zoo instance,
you probably have to use private Factories in Zoo class. However this seems to be a very awkward solution:

```
public class Falcon extends Animal {

    protected Falcon() {
    }

    protected static Falcon create() {
        return new Falcon();
    }
}

---

public class Dog extends Animal {

    protected Dog() {
    }

    protected static Dog create() {
        return new Dog();
    }
}


---

public class Zoo {

    public Falcon getFalcon() {
        return new FalconFactory().get();
    }

    public Dog getDog() {
        return new DogFactory().get();
    }

    private static class FalconFactory extends Falcon {
        private Falcon get() {
            return create();
        }
    }

    private static class DogFactory extends Dog {
        private Dog get() {
            return create();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is a good desing, but indeed this force user to use Zoo instance to create animals.

Of course a user still may create her own Factory that inherits from Falcon or Dog.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If it's not a good design (and user indeed can bypass it by extending) what is a good practice for implementing what I had in mind? There must be some, the idea of getting lib objects through a common security object (that has been logged in into) can't be new.

Comment: Look into dependency injection